# How to sum the values bigger than certain value in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Let us assume that:

- In the range `A1:A10`, I have values of time spent by various people.
- In cell `C1` I have the value since each you need to pay extra for each minute.
- In cell `D1` I would like to get the total sum of paid extra minutes.

In other words,

- if in the range `A1:A10`, I have the following values: `40,57,61,69,0,0,0,0,0,0`
- and in cell `C1`, I have `60`
- then the value in cell `D1` should be `(69-60)+(61-60)=10`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

If you want that as you change the value in C1,Answer should change then 
Try this the answer will change as you change the value in C1 (60 in your example)

```
=SUMIF(A1:A10,">"&C1,A1:A10)-C1*COUNTIF(A1:A10,">"&C1)
```

Thanks

Comment: I know already this method but it is not what I am looking for. I do not want to have ">60" hard coded but this value refer to C1. I tried ">c1" but it did not work work :(